# Where is the documentation for Play sbt-plugin (Build.scala)?

Tags: scala, build, playframework, sbt

I am currently using Play version 2.1.1, and trying to modify Build.scala.

By default, it imports a package called play.Project._

I have been trying to find out the API of this package so that I could customize our Build.scala file.

The only thing I have is this link:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Build

I also tried to find it from here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#package

Could anyone point me the location of this API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Build.scala` uses a `PlayProject` as described in the [Play SBT documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SBTSettings). This `PlayProject` essentially is an [sbt.Project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.Project), so you should have a closer look at the [corresponding sbt API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.Project%24). The `PlayProject` itself is defined [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/project/Build.scala) (line 147):

```
lazy val PlayProject = PlayRuntimeProject("Play", "play")
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies := runtime,
    sourceGenerators in Compile <+= sourceManaged in Compile map PlayVersion,
    mappings in(Compile, packageSrc) <++= scalaTemplateSourceMappings,
    parallelExecution in Test := false,
    sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (dependencyClasspath in TemplatesCompilerProject in Runtime, packageBin in TemplatesCompilerProject in Compile, scalaSource in Compile, sourceManaged in Compile, streams) map ScalaTemplates
  ).dependsOn(SbtLinkProject, PlayExceptionsProject, TemplatesProject, IterateesProject, JsonProject)
```

The `PlayRuntimeProject` is defined in the same file.

Comment: Thanks, @fynn! I still have a question though: The default Build.scala has this import statement: `import play.Project._`.  When we use it, we could say `play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/test"))`, I just wonder where exactly defines the API how to call play.Project? Specifically, the parameters that could be passed to play.Project constructor?  Also what is the difference between play.Project and PlayProject?